# Young's Inequality for vector's and matrices

Tags: inequality

Hi I want to know how is the Young's inequality for matrices and vectors and if i can use it for negative numbers or something like ($-ab\leq -\frac{a^2}{2} - \frac{b^2}{2}$)

thanks .

Comment: Not so clear to me what you are looking for: there is a version of Young's inequality that works for complex numbers, but perhaps it's not the one you think. Do you expect the inequality you wrote to be true for $a=1, b=2$ ?

Comment: How are you hoping to use such an inequality?

Comment: no I know this is false but want to know how to use this or something like this when a minus is multiplied to the vectors or matrices.

Answer (score 0):

No. It becomes from $(a-b)^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\ge0$